# Visual Studio deleting files it needs to debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I started running into a small problem regarding debugging my program. It would start off showing no errors, then I would press debug to test it. It would throw me an error saying
"Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug[programName].exe" because it was not found."
I have proceeded to tamper with various things, and came to the conclusion that it was a class  that I am using to read ini files by importing a dll. The two most likely lines in that class are these:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string val, string filePath);
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);
```

To test this, I removed the class and all references from the project, and it would build the project successfully. Then, I could look at the path and find the executable that was previously missing. Thinking the problem fixed, I put the class back in and as you would expect, it broke with the same error. It actually deleted the executable file before building, so in my head, it is obvious why it couldn't be found.

However, the not so obvious part is: The program was building and executing with this class in it up until this morning with no changes performed on it. Plus, the class works perfectly inside of my Unity3D game where it is reading the ini file this c# program creates.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and if there is a fix to it? I already tried creating a new project and re-importing everything, and it produces the same errors.

**EDIT**

After commenting and uncommenting each line, I found that the three commented lines in this are causing the problem:

```
public bool SaveToIni()
    {
        IniFile file = new IniFile("/LoadUpSettings.ini");
        try
        {
            file.IniWriteValue("Screen", "Screen Height", cbbScreenHeight.SelectedItem.ToString());
            file.IniWriteValue("Screen", "Screen Width", cbbScreenWidth.SelectedItem.ToString());
            //file.IniWriteValue("Controllers", "Razer Hydra", ckbRazerHydra.Checked.ToString());
            //file.IniWriteValue("Controllers", "Oculus Rift", ckbOculusRift.Checked.ToString());
            //file.IniWriteValue("Screen", "Fullscreen", ckbFullscreen.Checked.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all values");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the IniWriteValue function inside the IniFile class.

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);
public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key)
{
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
    int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp, 255, this.path);
    return temp.ToString();
}
```

Oddly enough, if i remove the ckbRazerHydra.Checked.ToString(), and put in a standard string such as "True", it still doesn't work, although with those 3 lines commented out, the project builds completely.

**EDIT**
I managed to fix this problem to an extent. I just have to run my program in release version. If I run it in debug mode, I will always get the error saying the exe couldn't be copied because it wasn't found. However, Release mode seems to almost always work.

Comment: "up until this morning with no changes performed on it." - Did you verify this statement in source control by looking at project level history?

Comment: Did you add a reference to a file that was in the obj or bin folders?

Comment: I did not add a reference to anything. And, as I am the only person working on it, I am positive there were no changes. I used it last night and the debug ran fine. Then this morning, I ran it again without changing anything, just to see what next I had to do, and it threw that error.

Comment: You specifically said in your question that you removed all references from your project and it started working again.  I am assuming that one of your references is referencing a file in your obj folder.  It should not be.  Forget about what you might have done between the time it last worked and the time it stopped working.  It could have been something you did days or weeks ago and the problem didn't occur until you did a clean or a rebuild.

Comment: No no, you misunderstand, when I say I removed all references, I mean i removed all calls to the class, and excluded the class from the project.

Comment: Is this all within one project or do you have a library containing the class causing the issue and you're trying to build a project referencing that library? I've had issues with visual studio not copying the references required by a referenced library. I had to make the missing reference directly in the project I was trying to build.

Comment: It is all in one project, and the problem arises from reading or writing the boolean value to a string.

Comment: Is this a compile-time or runtime error?

Comment: Compile time, and I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but Boolean.Truestring should print out "True", but I get the same error if I try to use a message box to display, or print it to the console

Answer (score 0):

The bin and obj folders are meant for output only.  When you tell Visual Studio to do a clean or a rebuild it will delete all files in these folders.  You can safely delete these folders at any time and you shouldn't lose anything in the process.

You are never meant to place any files in these folders.  If you want to add an external assembly (EXE or DLL) to your project you should add it to your project using the Add->Existing Item command on a project.  Then you can tell your project to reference that file and it will use the local relative path.

For example, if you create a "lib" folder in your project root and place `some.dll` inside it, you can then add a reference to the file located in your project and it will use the relative path `..\lib\some.dll`.

Comment: I have tried doing a clean, it was actually the first thing I tried, with no success. I just deleted the bin and obj folders, and it throws the same error.

Comment: Where in your project folder structure is the assembly (DLL or EXE) that you have referenced which contains your INI file functions?

Comment: It is simply a class file, located in the default namespace for my project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with files in your current project that you have set to

**Copy to output directory=copy always/copy if newer**

When you add a file this way VS will delete all other previous files that other projects dumped into your current project bin/.

In order to avoid this situation add the files and leave them with **Copy to output directory=Do not copy** option and then use **MSBuild Copy task** to dump your files.

If you are using docker you can simple put a COPY command - the same thing but not with MSBuild.

I believe this is the default behavior of some this MSBuild internal task and a workaround is the only option.